# Create network from dataframe using common column

Tags: python, pandas, csv, networkx

I'm currently trying to generate a Network-Graph with NetworkX on Python.
The Dataset has the following format (it's a CSV):

```
Id, Tag
0, 'science'
0, 'history'
1, 'sports'
3, 'sci-fi'
3, 'history'
3, 'music'
```

The Goal is to show the relation between the tags. F.e. Science is really closely related to History because they share the same Id. Now here's where I'm stuck:
How can I create a Table/Matrix that has 2 columns for NetworkX to use as Source(-Tag) and Target(-Tag) with Python?

I tried creating a Dataframe with Pandas and then using the same column twice, but that didn't work for me.

Comment: How is sports related to history?

Comment: It's related because they have the same id

Comment: But they don't. Sports' id is 1.

Comment: My bad, I corrected it.

Comment: What did you try so far? Please provide [a minimal an verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: Makes sense in that case :) Precisely `Sport` would be the only isolated node

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To connect nodes based on the `Id`, here's one approach, you can gruopby the `Id`, aggregate the groups to lists, and build a directed graph adding the lists as paths:

```
df = pd.read_csv('my_file.csv', sep=', ')
l = df.groupby('Id').Tag.agg(list).tolist()
# [['science', 'history'], ['sports'], ['sci-fi', 'history', 'music']]

G=nx.Graph()
for sl in l:
    nx.add_path(G, sl)

nx.draw(G, node_color='lightblue', 
        with_labels=True, 
        node_size=800)
```

[image]

---

For a directed graph:

```
G=nx.DiGraph()
for sl in l:
    nx.add_path(G, sl)

nx.draw(G, node_color='lightblue', 
        with_labels=True, 
        node_size=800)
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks a lot, that's exactly what i was looking for! :)
Do you know if there's any way to optimize _l = df.groupby('Id').Tag.agg(list).tolist()_ ?
It get's really slow with bigger sets...

Comment: No prob :) Try `df.groupby('Id').Tag.agg(list).values.tolist()` @HelloNirvanaNorway